# How to convert JSON into CSV in Spark?

Tags: json, csv, apache-spark, emr

My input file is line-delimited JSON objects (one object per line). Not every key is guaranteed to exist in each and every object.

After reading in the input file, how can I convert it to CSV where the header is the combined list of all possible keys. If a particular object doesn't have a key-value, that column is just empty.

Comment: Give an example of your data, what you have, what you want to achieve so people can help you

Comment: If the data is small enough that a single partition is feasable then you could have your code compute the union of the key names in one pass then convert the data in a second pass.  If the data is too big for a single partition then this naive approach won't work because it's possible that there could be some keys in one partition not present in the other but this is exactly the sort of thing you can handle with separate transformation steps.  First compute the (relatively small) union of the key names in one step, do the csv formatting in a second step and then merge the final results.